# Using GIT First time : allow other users access to project

Tags: git

I just started using GIT for version control. I used the git init to create a repository. However, I want other users on the server to access it as well ..

Can someone point me towards what command I should be looking at?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "other users on the server"?  Will people be logging in directly, accessing via ssh, using HTTP, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as they can acces to your local repository, they can fork, pull ...
If you want to share a central repository, look for "bare repository"